# Getting Error while going through with django doc

Tags: django

The following code I'm Typing in ./manage.py shell

> > > import datetime
> > >       from django.db import models
> > >       class ContactForm(forms.Form):
> > >       ...         date = DateField(widget=CalendarWidget)
> > >       ...         name = CharField(max_length=40, widget=OtherWidget)
> > >       ... 
> > >       Traceback (most recent call last):
> > >         File "", line 1, in 
> > >         File "", line 2, in ContactForm
> > >       NameError: name 'DateField' is not defined
> > >       
> > >       If there anything else to import. If so, please tell me about that and thanks in advance...

Answer (score 2):

```
class ContactForm(forms.Form):
    date = forms.DateField(widget=CalendarWidget)
    name = forms.CharField(max_length=40, widget=OtherWidget)
```

Comment: but in the form media documentation of djnago, the code given as per my code above for date & name...!!! and that raises the same error that seen in the above code... please tell why is that so...?

Comment: link of the documentation?

Comment: link:--https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/topics/forms/media/  and the Topic is Media on Forms the last one on that page.

Comment: @jayrawal This is done by importing first `from django import forms` and after that `from django.forms.fields import *` Take a look at my edit.

Comment: Yeah, I see... I don't know why, maybe you can ask directly to them why it's incomplete. There are many people confused on the django docu

Answer (score 1):

You should import `django.forms`:

```
from django import forms

class ContactForm(forms.Form):
    date = forms.DateField(widget=CalendarWidget)
    name = forms.CharField(max_length=40, widget=OtherWidget)
```

EDIT: Or to make your code work you can do:

```
from django import forms
from django.forms.fields import *

class ContactForm(forms.Form):
    date = DateField(widget=CalendarWidget)
    name = CharField(max_length=40, widget=OtherWidget)
```

Comment: @jayrawal Use `print f.media`, not simply `f.media`. `f.media` will call the media `__repr__` method, while `print f.media`, will call it's `__str__` method.

Comment: THANKS A LOT....... IT WORKS AND I HAVE UNDERSTAND THE REASON BEHIND THAT... THANKS AGAIN....